# How to write fixed length records in Protbuf-net?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, fixed-length-record

Here is the main part of my code to Serialize using Protobuf-net.  I have a very large number of records that I loop through and write to file.

I now want to make all records a FIXED SIZE so that later in Deserialization I can skip several records at once.

How to I modify this code to write FIXED LENGTH records?

```
       List<SP> SortedData = Data.OrderBy(o => o.DT).ToList();

        string LastdatFileName = "";
        FileStream outBin = null;

        foreach (var d in SortedData)
        {
            string binFileName = "n" + symbol + d.DT.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".dat";

            if (!datFileName.Equals(LastdatFileName))
            {
                if (outBin != null)
                {
                    outBin.Close();
                }

                outBin = File.Create(dbDirectory + @"\" + binFileName, 2048, FileOptions.None);
                LastdatFileName = datFileName;
            }

            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(outBin, d.ToTickRecord(),PrefixStyle.Base128);

        }

        outBin.Close();
```

The record

```
  [ProtoContract]
    public class TickRecord
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public DateTime DT;
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public double BidPrice;
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public double AskPrice;
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public int BidSize;
        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public int AskSize;

        public TickRecord(DateTime DT, double BidPrice, double AskPrice, int BidSize, int AskSize)
        {
            this.DT = DT;
            this.BidPrice = BidPrice;
            this.AskPrice = AskPrice;
            this.BidSize = BidSize;
            this.AskSize = AskSize;

        }
}
```

Deserialize

```
             long skipRate = 10;


                    while ((tr = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<TickRecord>(fs, PrefixStyle.Base128)) != null) //fs.Length > fs.Position)
                    {

                        count++;

                        fs.Position += (38 * skipRate);
                        if (fs.Position > fs.Length)
                            break;

                        //Console.WriteLine("> " + tr.ToString());

                    }
```

SSCCE for Marc Gravell

You will need to create 2 buttons Serialize and Deserialize.

Serialize creates a dummy data file.

Deserialize reads through it.

Comment out the fs.Position line to see raw read through of entire file. Takes 12 secs on my machine.
Then uncomment it and file will skip 10 records each time. Was hoping for a factor 10 improvement in speed, BUT takes 8 secs on my machine. So I assume change fs.Position is expensive.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ProtoBuf;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BinTest3
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Serialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FileStream outBin = null;

            string binFileName = @"C:\binfile.dft";
            outBin = File.Create(binFileName, 2048, FileOptions.None);

            DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

            TickRecord tr = new TickRecord(d, 1.02, 1.03,200,300);

            for (int i =0; i < 20000000; i++)
            {
                tr.BidPrice += 1;
                Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(outBin, tr, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            }

            outBin.Close();
            label1.Text = "Done ";
        }

        private void Deserialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            FileStream fs;
            string binFileName = @"C:\binfile.dft";

            fs = new FileStream(binFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4 * 4096);
            long skipRate =10;
            int count = 0;
            TickRecord tr;

            long skip = (38*skipRate);
            try
            {
                while ((tr = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<TickRecord>(fs, PrefixStyle.Base128)) != null) //fs.Length > fs.Position)
                {
                    count++;

                    fs.Position += skip;  //Comment out this line to see raw speed

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            fs.Close();

            sw.Stop();
            label1.Text = "Time taken: " + sw.Elapsed + " Count: " + count.ToString("n0");

        }
    }


    [ProtoContract]
    public class TickRecord
    {

        [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
        public DateTime DT;
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public double BidPrice;
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public double AskPrice;
        [ProtoMember(4, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
        public int BidSize;
        [ProtoMember(5, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
        public int AskSize;

        public TickRecord()
        {

        }

        public TickRecord(DateTime DT, double BidPrice, double AskPrice, int BidSize, int AskSize)
        {
            this.DT = DT;
            this.BidPrice = BidPrice;
            this.AskPrice = AskPrice;
            this.BidSize = BidSize;
            this.AskSize = AskSize;

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: The protocol buffer wire format just doesn't "do" fixed length records. You could potentially write blocks of N records at a time (as a separate message) - because the wire format uses a length prefix, that would let you skip over those N records very quickly (without parsing anything else, at least theoretically).

Comment: @JonSkeet My goal is to skip VARYING numbers of records on Deserialize. So it would be convenient NOT to specify the blocking on Serialize.

Comment: As I've said, the Protocol Buffers wire format just isn't designed like that. The closest I could think of would be to have a message format with some "padding" fields that you'd have to carefully construct for each message to get it to the right size. It would be pretty fiddly though.

Comment: I don't mind the fiddly on the Serialize side. And process can be slow. But I need lightning faste Deserialize. Any ideas how I might add a "padding" field?

Comment: I'd add a bytes field, and study the wire format (documented in the main protobuf project site) to work out how many bytes the tag will take up. Depending on the range of padding you need, you may need two fields to cope with when adding one mire byte would expand the tag too.

Comment: Can you give me link for Protobuf documentation. I can't find it - all I see is small "Getting Started" site.

Comment: @JonSkeet Also, is the an alternative to Protobuf that allows me to work with fixed lengths?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/ and in particular https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

Comment: Although now you've shown your TickRecord, if you make sure the `int` values are serialized as `fixed32` - and depending on how `DateTime` is serialized - it sounds like it would be fixed length anyway. I don't know whether you can easily affect how the `DateTime` is stored. (If you could serialize that as a `fixed64` number of ticks, that would be pretty simple.)

Comment: I checked what is actually written and it varies between 39-42 bytes

Comment: Well yes, I suspect you need to configure the attributes to use fixed numeric encodings. That shouldn't be hard - it's only the DateTime that might be tricky.

Comment: Where do I look to find that - is it a Protbuf setting?

Comment: I've never used protobuf.net before, and I found it within about 30 seconds... https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Attributes I'm trying to write up an answer now, but it's important to be able to research things yourself too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick look at the documentation, I think you want something like:

```
[ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
public DateTime DT;
[ProtoMember(2,)]
public double BidPrice;
[ProtoMember(3)]
public double AskPrice;
[ProtoMember(4, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
public int BidSize;
[ProtoMember(5, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
public int AskSize;
```

That should be fine for the numeric values - I'm not *sure* whether the `DataFormat` attribute will work for the `DateTime` field. An alternative would be to have a `long Ticks` which is serialized with a `FixedSize` data format, and then a property which converted to/from `DateTime`. Looking at the code though, I *think* it will be okay as written above. There's no need to specify the data format for `double` as that's always written as a fixed-size value anyway.

Comment: Understood Jon. I did actually look at that page before - but to me it was not obvious that's what it was for. I am still trying to find more Protobuf-net documentation. However, your solution appears to work - thanks very much

Comment: @MarcGravell That's odd. Please see my edit above showing Deserialize code. EVen though I am skipping 10 records each time (my structure size is 38).  The timetaken for (200 mio records) goes from 2mins to 1.45min! Do you think that is because changing fs.Postion is expensive?

Comment: @Man very hard to say without a concrete example

Comment: @MarcGravell  Please see edi of question. I have added a concrete example